# Inetgrate and Communicate multiple Angular applications on same page (SPA)

Tags: javascript, angular, architecture

I just start thinking about communication between two angular (or others framework) applications - what is the best way to do that.

For now, in my application, I used `iframe` to include the second app and then thanks to `postMessage` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)) I can handle actions between apps.

But this solution is getting **really hard** to maintain because I didn't expect at the begging that I will have to handle soo much type of events.

**Let's give you an example:**
On Facebook when you go to someone profile you can click "Send message" and it will open a new window on chat application. In other way you can also click on some button in their chat and it will send some action to "main" application.

[image: facebook open chat screenshot]

I just read few articles and start thinking about using `WebSockets`, using firebase etc but I want to make some more research and ask more expired developers (yes, you! :) ) what they thinking.

So, my question is:

1. What is the best approach to include two (or more) angular apps?
2. What is the best approach to handle communication between these apps?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a really fun problem to solve. There are a number of different ways to go about this, and I'm not sure how your website architecture is setup and what constraint's you have, but I can at least provide some suggestions.

#### Possible Solutions

1. Look into separating separate functionality into lazy loaded Angular modules, and treat them as separate websites altogether.

I've done this for a few applications and it gives you some of the flexibility you're looking for. For this to work with your application communication constraints, there are a number of different ways to approach it.

If you can get away with a single application, then you're going to want to look into state management solutions like [NgXS](https://www.ngsx.org/), [NgRX](https://ngrx.io/), [Akita](https://netbasal.gitbook.io/akita/), or [roll your own statemanagement](https://dev.to/avatsaev/simple-state-management-in-angular-with-only-services-and-rxjs-41p8). I personally roll my own for these things because I rarely need to overhead of the bigger frameworkss, but to each their own.

If you can't get away with a single application, then you're going to want to separate your state into something like FireBase, or a custom websocket app. This would give you better persistence of state, and also allow you to connect completely independent web applications to one another.

2. Another promising solution to things like this is the tool [SingleSpa](https://single-spa.js.org/).

Single spa is a meta web framework that can help navigate and orchestrate multiple SPA's written in different libraries/frameworks into a single application. This would allow you to re-use the existing website that you're using the `<iframe>` for, but have it bundled within the same parent application. I'm not too familiar with this framework in practice, but I have some coworkers and peers who use it, and it seems promising.

3. Take a step back and identify the core problem you're trying to solve

This one isn't trying to troll or anything, just helping to take a step back and look over your application from a 10,000 foot overview. Look over how the data is being passed in the solution, are you solving the problem directly? Or is this solution a hack to make due with the constraints that you had at the beginning. Don't be afraid to rebuild parts of the application, or service. Theres a reason people talk about the [10 to 1 rule of writing code](https://www.ybrikman.com/writing/2018/08/12/the-10-to-1-rule-of-writing-and-programming/).

I understand time and complexity constraints, you have deadlines and other things to deal with. Just make sure you're solving the right problem and thinking about the different edge cases you can leverage to your advantage.

---

I recognize after writing this out that its not a direct `answer` per say, but I hope it helped. Message me if you have any questions on this stuff.

Comment: Actually, you are right. Maybe it will be better to get a few steps back and include the second app into the main app, I already using lazy loading but I considering to use also this concept:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nX_HhiqmFAI

Comment: @Lyczos Best of luck with everything! And yeah I mean every project is different, but in a lot of cases you can help yourself out the most by simplifying a lot of things. That video seems cool I'll have to watch it later, thanks!